# fitsSystemWindows="true" doesn't work after calling setContentView()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-window

For an app I'm developing I wanted to reload the UI after a user input (basically resetting it completely after they made changes to it). I wanted to try avoiding destroying/recreating the activity and use `setContentView()` instead because it's a lot faster.

However when I do that I'm having an issue: the newly created UI doesn't respect the `fitsSystemWindows="true"` and part of it ends up behind the android's status bar.

I managed to boil it down to that code example to test it :

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                reloadUI();
            }
        });

    }

    public void reloadUI() {
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
    }
}
```

When I load the app, I get the expected layout, that is a simple button on top of the screen, right below the status bar:

[image]

However, once I click the button which calls `setContentView` a second time (showing the same XML), the Button gets behind the status bar:

[image]

Calling `mainContainer.getMeasuredHeight()` to check what happens gives me 1848px on the first start of the app (on a screen that is 1920px tall, so its height is 72px less than the whole screen, 72px being the height of the status bar), but once I call setContentView again the `mainContainer.getMeasuredHeight()` gives me 1920px.

Am I missing something here? I could force the mainContainer to stick to a 1848px height with a 72px top padding, but I'd prefer to avoid an ugly hack like this.

Comment: Why are you calling `setContentView` again? Instead you can `invalidate` the whole `viewgroup`.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't reset everything properly. For example in my use case there are some custom views that the user can set to a specific color (that is stored inside the custom view class), and this isn't reset to the default when calling invalidate, it just redraws the UI. I could refactor part of my app to deal with invalidate properly, but I thought using setContentView would be faster to get a fresh start and reloading the UI to the default state.

Answer (score 5):

So, what you want is to ask the framework to dispatch once more `WindowInsets` to your root view. That's precisely what [`ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(View)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#requestApplyInsets(android.view.View)) will do:

> Ask that a new dispatch of `View.onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets)` be performed. This falls back to `View.requestFitSystemWindows()` where available.

Applying just one line should resolve all your concerns:

```
    public void reloadUI() {
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        // `R.id.mainContainer` is the id of the root view in `R.layout.layout`
        ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(findViewById(R.id.mainContainer));
    }
```

Comment: Perfect solution with enough simple information. When all other solutions I found failed, this one worked right away with no complications.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution is to change the `rootView` `marginTop` or `paddingTop` to adapt to the `View` manually.